# jQuery click event seems to be kind of late

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I'm working on a Facebook reaction bar so it is pretty hard to copy the code here because it has a lot of events binded but all of you got facebook so if you want to check it by yourself - please do it.

The thing is that I managed to move the reaction bar under the react root and now I wanted to make the clicked reaction counter change the background color of itself to green.

And everything is working almost good excluding one thing: it is one click behind. To make you understand better I recorded little example how it looks. The red pulse ring appears when I click: https://vid.me/HqYp

Here is the changing code:

```
$(this).find('div._iu-[role="toolbar"]').bind('click',function(){
                $(this).find('p.counter').each(function(){$(this).css('background-color','#48649F');});
                $(this).find('span[aria-pressed="true"]').find('p.counter').css('background-color','green');
            });
```

`$(this)` is `div[id*="post"]` so in `$(this)` I'm getting div with the whole post.

I thought that maybe I should use a callback function after changing-every-counter-to-default-color function but I don't know am I right and if it's right solution.

Thanks from above. (:

Comment: That all depends on when `aria-pressed` is set to `"true"`.

Comment: I was sure that you are right but then: https://vid.me/pAzd As you can see icon is clicked, aria-pressed changes, nothing happens, changes only after second click.

Comment: Then `aria-pressed` is being updated after your click event. It will only change the color of the child of the element with `aria-pressed="true"`. Therefore, `aria-pressed` has not been updated to the most recent element by the time your click event goes off.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably simplify this a bit. Although without the html structure I can't know for sure how the layout of the function works with respect to the event origin.  Also I am not sure when the aria-pressed is set to true so I made the function a bit more generic. You simply add a data attribute to target the span you want to be targeted by the click.

```
<div class="_lu-" role="toolbar" data-target=".facebook-counter">
```

Later in your javascript you do the following

```
var $t = $(this);
var $t.target = $(this).data('target');
$t.on('click','div._lu-[role="toolbar"]', function() {
   $t.find($t.target).css({
      'background-color':'green'
   }).siblings().css({'background-color','#48649F'});
});
```

This code is assuming first that your spans are in the same container, and second that the first `$(this)` refers to the parent container of this whole toolbar, and last that you have put `data-target=""` attributes with selectors for the appropriate target you want to affect.

This is a sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toolbar').on('click','.toolbar-item .icon', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if(!this.$) this.$ = $(this);
    if(!this.parent) this.parent = this.$.parent();
    if(!this.counter) this.counter = this.$.siblings('.counter');
    
    this.parent.addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    var count = this.counter.data('value');
    count++;
    this.counter.data('value',count);
    this.counter.html(count);
  });
});
```

```css
.toolbar {
  font-size:0;
  text-align:center;
}

.toolbar-item .icon {
  background:#FFF;
  padding:30px;
  border:1px solid #AAA;
  border-radius:100%;
  margin:0 20%;
  transition:0.8s ease all;
}

.selected .icon {
  background:#369;
}

.toolbar-item .counter {
  background:#E0E0E0;
  margin:0 10px;
  transition:0.4s ease background;
}

.selected .counter {
  background:#509050;
}

.toolbar-item {
  font-size:10pt;
  width:25%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="toolbar-item">
    <div class="icon">Like</div>
    <div class="counter" data-value="0">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="toolbar-item">
    <div class="icon">Wow</div>
    <div class="counter" data-value="0">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="toolbar-item">
    <div class="icon">Sad</div>
    <div class="counter" data-value="0">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="toolbar-item">
    <div class="icon">Angry</div>
    <div class="counter" data-value="0">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As of jQuery 1.7 they introduced the .on('click', function().... method. Try that instead and see if you get the same results.

Comment: Version of Jquery is not at all a problem here. -1

Comment: `.on` is the preferred way to do it but `.bind` still works as intended.

Answer (score -2):

Quick answer without having tested or the time to test your code.  I recently had a performance issue with a nested function, so maybe look at that second line with the .each() method.